# Running a C# program with command line prompts in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am running an inherited project written in C# inside Visual Studio Code. In order for this application to run, it needs to take command line input (-t, -h, etc). How do I test this from inside Visual Studio?

Currently (I've been learning dotnet, C#, VS, etc as I go) I have a hello world program I can run from vsc's terminal. For a reason I haven't been able to pinpoint, probably how I installed it, `dotnet run` isn't recognized - I have to feed it an explicit path to dotnet.exe: `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe run`

How can I do this when the program requires command line input? My shot in the dark of `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe run -t` predictably didn't work, but I'm not sure what else to try.

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, so what you are saying is that, when you run/debug(F5) the project, you have to go to `cmd` and type in the `path` then `run` before the application can run, is that right?

Comment: Check the section "To build and run the Command Line Parameters samples within Visual Studio" in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs8hbt1w(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Malky.Kid, right. F5 isn't quite working - I suspect I just have the project set up wrong - so I'm bypassing it entirely and just using the command line until I can work out this first problem

Comment: @EmilyColeman why not use an express edition of visual studio? It's free

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `dotnet.exe run` to start your application you need add the `--` switch statement to instruct `dotnet.exe` to pass the arguments to your application. For example

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-run#options)

`dotnet.exe run -- -arg1 -arg2 (etc)` notice the `--` after the `dotnet` arguments and before your program specific arguments.

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1385)

Answer (score 4):

**Run with Terminal**

When you run your code using terminal you must add ' -- ' to tell dotnet you are running your code with an argument/s

> C:>dotnet run -- `<your arguments here>`

**Run with Debugger**

- Locate your .vscode folder inside your project if not create one.
- Open the launch.json file
- You will see a json object and add your arguments inside the "args" key.

#### launch.json

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "args": [], // PUT YOUR ARGUMENTS HERE
             ...
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add a comment to Nico's answer but I lack sufficient reputation points. I was confused by the dash character in front of each arg: "-arg1 -arg2 (etc)". For clarity I would like to point out that .NET Core 2.1 seems to not need this. In the case of my console app, it takes a date for the first arg, an integer for the second, then an operator (+ or -) for the third arg. If I entered the following:

```
C:\>dotnet run -- -7/13/2018 -30 -+
```

I found that the leading dash in front of each arg was passed into the program along with the intended arg and I ended up trying to date parse "-7/13/2018"

I got the expected result when I entered it like this:

```
C:\>dotnet run -- 7/13/2018 30 +
```

Comment: Dashes are just convention for programs that accept command line arguments, usually representing flags for the program. they are passed exactly as-is, and if the programmer decides that they want users to type the dashes (again, convention), then they will have to strip them from the input themselves within the program

Answer (score 0):

Since OP is specifically asking about how to do this in Visual Studio Code, they are likely using VSCode's run feature (not the dotnet CLI as other answers assume), to run their application.  In this case, the proper way to supply command line arguments is via the `.vscode\launch.json` file.

Add an `args` array attribute to your configuration and populate it with the arguments you would like to pass.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        // ... ,
        "args": ["-arg1", "-arg2"]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Right click on your project
2. Click Properties
3. Click Debug in the Properties window
4. Under "start options:"
5. Add a "Command Line Argument:" = run -t
6. Add a "Working Directory:" try the bin\debug directory

Comment: I expect the flag is because this answer applies to Visual Studio not VSCode.